# Android espresso automation test, I can not detect the correct text displayed in TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, automation, android-espresso

The implementation looks like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_grade_percentage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:text="@string/score_grade_append"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lbl_overall_grade_description" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Resources are like this:

```
<string name="grade_percentage_append">Your current grade: %1$s</string>
<string name="excellent">Excellent</string>
<string name="very_good">Very Good</string>
<string name="good">Good</string>
<string name="needs_improvement">Needs Improvement</string>
<string name="no_gradee">No Grade</string>
```

and the display of the text on mobile is:

```
90% Your current grade: Excellent
```

or

```
- Your current grade: No Grade
```

but it only can assert the displayed text like this:

```
percentageGrade.check(matches(withText(R.string.grade_percentage_append)))
```

and I need help on how to assert the correct displayed text